# Google Cloud Run does not find os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-bigquery, google-cloud-run

I am trying to deploy a Python app in Google Cloud Run to perform some tasks automatically and these tasks require access to my BigQuery.
I have tested the implementation in localhost through Cloud Shell, and it worked just as expected. Then I created a Cloud Run Service and all functions that do not require access to BigQuery work normally, but when I they require, I get the following error:
`google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: File /XXXXXX/gbq.json was not found.`

However, the file is there (the folders are correct, and I also tested adding copies of the file in other folders): [image]

Any suggestions to solve the problem or a workaround I could use? 
Thanks in advance

### ADDITIONAL INFO:

#### main.py function:

(the bottom part of the code is used to test the app in localhost, which works perfectly)

```
from flask import Flask, request
from test_py import test as t

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.get("/")
def hello():
    """Return a friendly HTTP greeting."""
    chamado = request.args.get("chamado", default="test")
    print(chamado)
    if chamado == 'test':
        dados = f'chamado = test?\n{chamado == "test"}\n{t.show_data(chamado)}'
    elif chamado == 'bigqueer':
        dados = f'chamado = test?\n{chamado == "test"}\n{t.show_bq_data()}'
    else:
        dados = f'chamado = test?\n{chamado == "test"}\n{t.show_not_data(chamado)}'
    
    print(dados)
    return dados


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Development only: run "python main.py" and open http://localhost:8080
    # When deploying to Cloud Run, a production-grade WSGI HTTP server,
    # such as Gunicorn, will serve the app.
    app.run(host="localhost", port=8080, debug=True)
```

#### BigQuery class:

```
class GoogleBigQuery:
    def __init__(self):
        os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = '/XXXXXX/gbq.json'
        self.client = bq.Client()

    def executar_query(self, query):
        client_query = self.client.query(query)
        result = client_query.result()
        return result
```

#### Cloud Run deploy:

```
gcloud run deploy pythontest \
  --source . \
  --platform managed \
  --region $REGION \
  --allow-unauthenticated
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**YOU DO NOT NEED THAT**

Excuse my first brutal words but it's extremely dangerous to do what you do. Let me explain.

In your container, you put, in plain text a secret. Keep in mind that your container is like a zip. There is nothing secret, encrypted in it. You can convince yourselves by using [dive](https://github.com/wagoodman/dive) and exploring your container layers and data.

Therefore: DO NOT DO THAT!

---

So now, what to do?

On Google Cloud, all the services can use the [Metadata server](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/metadata/overview) to get credentials. The client libraries leverage it and you can rely on the default credential with you initialise your code. That mechanism is named [ADC](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production).

In your code, simpy remove that line: `os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = '/XXXXXX/gbq.json'`

So that, when you deploy your Cloud Run service, [specify the runtime service account](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/service-accounts) that you want to use. That's all! The Google Cloud environment and libraries will do the rest

Comment: Thanks!! That worked! I had to add bigquery permissions to the default service account used.

Comment: I tried log the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS from the Cloud Run, and it returns none. Does Cloud Run find the ADC's some other way?

Comment: On Cloud Run, as any Google Cloud Service, there is a metadata server that provide credential and runtime data (location, machine type, ...). The client library know how to communicate with that metadata server and can use that credentials. It's transparent for you!